# Function or class that returns array of all possible replacements of a string

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, str-replace

I am looking for a function or class that substitutes given string and returns array of all possible replacements.
In other words I am seeking for a magic_function:

```
function magic_function( $str, $find, $replace )
{
     $arr = array();

     // some magic stuff

     return $arr;
}

var_dump( magic_function( 'aaa', 'a', 'b' ) );

/*
    should return:

    Array(
          'aab',
          'aba',
          'baa',
          'bba',
          'bab',
          'abb',
          'bbb'
    );
*/
```

I am thinking of using explode and then somehow looping through that array, but maybe there is a simpler way? Maybe with regex? Any ideas? :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what.. what's your actual question?

Answer (score 2):

explode and loop seems fairly simple.

```
<?php

function magic_function ($str, $find, $replace) {
   $parts = explode($find, $str);
   $n = count($parts)-1;
   $p = 1<<$n;

   for ($i=1; $i<$p; $i++) {
      for ($perm="", $seps=$i, $j=0; $j<$n; $seps>>=1, $j++) {
         $perm .= $parts[$j] . ($seps&1 ? $replace : $find);
      }
      $res[] = $perm . $parts[$n];
   }

   return $res;
}
```

Start from `$i=0` to include the no-replacement case.